# Two TTS in one activity in Android Studio Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, text-to-speech

I want to have two or more TTS in one activity. I have 4 textViews and want to be able to play each one seperatly.

I found a code and can play one, but can not play two.  I copied the code and changed the variables but did not work.

Pretty basic in Android so any help is great, if this question has been asked before I apologize as I could not find an answer.

Please, Kotlin answers only. My code is shown below.

```
package com.example.testmisc1

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button

import android.widget.TextView

import java.util.*

class ListeningActivity : AppCompatActivity(), 
TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
private var tts: TextToSpeech? = null
private var btnSpeak: Button? = null
private var etSpeak: TextView? = null
private var btnSpeak2: Button? = null
private var etSpeak2: TextView? = null


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.listening)

    // view binding button and edit text
    btnSpeak = findViewById(R.id.btnText)
    etSpeak = findViewById(R.id.textlike1)
    btnSpeak2 = findViewById(R.id.btnText2)
    etSpeak2 = findViewById(R.id.textlike2)

    btnSpeak!!.isEnabled = false

    // TextToSpeech(Context: this, OnInitListener: this)
    tts = TextToSpeech(this, this)

    btnSpeak!!.setOnClickListener { speakOut() }

}

override fun onInit(status: Int) {
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        val result = tts!!.setLanguage(Locale.US)

        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result 
== TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            Log.e("TTS","The Language not supported!")
        } else {
            btnSpeak!!.isEnabled = true
        }
    }
}
private fun speakOut() {
    val text = etSpeak!!.text.toString()
    tts!!.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null,"")
}

public override fun onDestroy() {
    // Shutdown TTS when
    // activity is destroyed
    if (tts != null) {
        tts!!.stop()
        tts!!.shutdown()
    }
    super.onDestroy()
}


}

class ListeningActivity2 : AppCompatActivity(), 
TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
private var tts: TextToSpeech? = null
private var btnSpeak2: Button? = null
private var etSpeak2: TextView? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.listening)

    // view binding button and edit text
    btnSpeak2 = findViewById(R.id.btnText2)
    etSpeak2 = findViewById(R.id.textlike2)

    btnSpeak2!!.isEnabled = false

    // TextToSpeech(Context: this, OnInitListener: this)
    tts = TextToSpeech(this, this)

    btnSpeak2!!.setOnClickListener { speakOut1() }

}

override fun onInit(status: Int) {
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        val result = tts!!.setLanguage(Locale.US)

        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result 
== TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            Log.e("TTS","The Language not supported!")
        } else {
            btnSpeak2!!.isEnabled = true
        }
    }
}
private fun speakOut1() {
    val text = etSpeak2!!.text.toString()
    tts!!.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null,"")
}

public override fun onDestroy() {
    // Shutdown TTS when
    // activity is destroyed
    if (tts != null) {
        tts!!.stop()
        tts!!.shutdown()
    }
    super.onDestroy()
}


}
```